# LINQ, Grouping on IEnumerable<object[]>

Tags: linq, group-by, ienumerable, linq-to-objects, grouping

I have the following elements (could be more than two):

```
new[] { new[] { "A" }, new[] { "B", "C" } }
new[] { new[] { "D" }, new[] { "E", "F" } }
```

I want to group them as follow:

"A", "D"

"B", "C", "E", "F"

What is the most optimum way (or at least a good way)?

Is it possible to store, somehow, that on the first pair "D" (and on second pair E" and "F") were not in the same array at the beginning?

Comment: How do you want this grouped exactly?  You question title does not seem to correspond with your question body.  It looks like you want the first items put into one collection and second items in another.

Comment: What exactly is the `IEnumerable<object[]>`? Is what you've shown us the contents of said IEnumerable? Are these two separate instances of `IEnumerable<object[]>`s? Could you just clarify the question all at once instead of making me have to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Yes, that is the content of two separate instances. I am scratching my head to find a way to group them {"A", "D"} and {"B","C", "E", "F"} however, after the grouping I will loose the information that "B","C" where on the 1st instance and "E","F" on the 2nd. (..However, even the simple group will work for me at this point!) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this yesterday. Not the most readable, but it accomplishes the objective.

```
new [] { 
    new[] { new[] { "A" }, new[] { "B", "C" } },
    new[] { new[] { "D" }, new[] { "E", "F" } }
}.SelectMany((x, arrayPos) => x.Select((y, itemPos) => new { y, arrayPos, itemPos }))
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.itemPos })
.Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.y.Select(z => new { z, y.arrayPos })))
```

The arrayPos value will indicate the original position.

Comment: Trying it. Will take a while.

Comment: Works! :) I don't know if it's the optimal way, I investigate generated IL on LINQPad. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Nikos, the generated IL won't tell you much about that in this case. You will see mostly bunch of calls to the extension methods, and it's their implementation that is important for performance.

Comment: Yes, indeed! However, you may see how many new classes are generated (adding pressure to GC) if this is called multiple times in short time periods.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the two in a collection:

```
var collections = new[]
{
    new[] { new[] { "A" }, new[] { "B", "C" } },
    new[] { new[] { "D" }, new[] { "E", "F" } }
};

var result = from first in collections
             from second in first.Select((x, i) => new {x, i})
             from third in second.x
             group third by second.i;
```

The result is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, string>>`, which means each member is a collection of `string`s that also has an `int` key. Note that the result may not be sorted, so the group for 1 may come first. If you don't want that, add `orderby` to the end of the query.

Comment: That's a nice solution but it could be more than two collections.

Comment: Trying it. Will take a while.

Comment: @svick - Nice solution. The use of the variables `first`, `second` & `third` threw me for a while. Made much more sense to me when I replaced them with `xs`, `xi` & `x` respectively. I'd also drop the "Assuming you have the two in a collection" at the start of your solution as it works for any `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>`. If this doesn't get marked as the answer I'd be stunned.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I thought about the variable names, but couldn't think of any good names. I agree that what I have there now is confusing, but so would be your names for me. And by collection, I did mean `IE<IE<IE<T>>>`, it wasn't clear from that question that is what OP has.